# reshape output or tf.gather(), tensorflow

Tags: reshape, tensorflow

I have a tensor in `[None, 100, 5, 50]` from `tf.gather(W,X)` and I want to reshape it to `[None, 100, 250])`
but using `tf.reshape (even with tf.pack)` shows me error of `Dimension(None)` because of dynamic aspect of the graph. 
is there any way to first reshape the inside of `tensor [100,5,50]` as far as the dimensions are known in graph and then using the `set_shape` having the `[None, 100, 250]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape) op doesn't understand partial shapes (i.e. those with a `None` for one or more dimensions), because they can be ambiguous: e.g. there could be many possible concrete shapes for a partial shape `[None, None, 50]`.

However, `tf.reshape()` also allows you to specify *one* of the dimensions as a wildcard, which will be chosen automatically, so you can use this in your case. To specify the wildcard, use `-1` as one of the dimensions:

```
input = ...
print input.get_shape()  ==> [None, 100, 5, 50]

reshaped = tf.reshape(input, [-1, 100, 250])
```